# URL redirection without query parameters, htaccess or php

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a URL /searched. I need to work this URL in multiple ways.

1. When someone type /searched it should get redirect to controller X without changing URL in the browser
2. When someone type `/searched?page=1` it should get redirect to controller X without changing URL in the browser and pass all query parameters to controller X
3. When someone type `/searched/<keyword>` it should get redirect to controller Y without changing URL in the browser
4. When someone type `/searched/<keyword>/<keyword1>` it should get redirect to controller Y without changing URL in the browser
5. When someone type `/searched/<keyword>?query=<keyword>` it should get redirect to controller Y. But change URL in browser to `/searched/<keyword>`.
   e.g. `http://localhost/searched/ocean?search_query=ocean should change to http://localhost/searched/ocean in browser`
6. When someone type `/searched/<keyword>/<keyword1>?query=<keyword1>` it should get redirect to controller Y. But change URL in browser to /searched//.

Scenario 1 to 4 is working fine with the below rules, I am struggling with scenario 5 & 6.

.htaccess rules I have tried

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} searched
RewriteRule ^searched$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}popularsearches [QSA,DPI]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (searched/)
RewriteRule ^searched/$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}popularsearches [QSA,DPI]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(page)
RewriteRule ^searched/$ popularsearches?controller=popularsearch [DPI]
RewriteRule ^searched$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}popularsearches [DPI]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(page)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (search_query)
RewriteRule ^searched/(.*?)/(.*?)$ search?controller=search&search_query=$2 [DPI]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(page)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(search_query)
RewriteRule ^searched/(.*?)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}search?controller=search&search_query=$1 [DPI]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly do share your tried htaccess rule file in your question, efforts by OP should be put in their questions which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have edited the question with htaccess rules I tried.

Comment: Thank you for sharing it, `controller X ` means home page etc? could you please clarify once.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 controller X means any controller, e.g. popularsearches. it could be any controller.